# How can I transform my solid mesh into fine dust (smoke) smoothly half-way through an animation?

Tags: animation, mesh, particles, smoke-simulation

I've created a mesh logo which has to be solid for a period of time in an animation. At a certain point in my animation, though, I would like it to dissolve into dust.

The problem is the transition between a solid object and smoke. I got the idea looking at a video that showed objects being destroyed, but that was done with the geometry of the object.

If I were to make my object smoke to begin with, it wouldn't look / behave / as it's meant to for the first part of the animation. On the other hand, if I were to break the object as many tutorials show, via a particle system, I don't know that it's possible to achieve the feel of smoke instead of the chunk particles that most tutorials show.

*How can I transform my solid mesh into fine dust (smoke) smoothly half-way through an animation?*

Comment: Under Smoke Cache, set the start frame to be whatever you want

Comment: @someonewithpc but the mesh will still exist. I can animate it's material to be invisible, but it seems that that will look corny and obvious; the text will be shown becoming invisible while replaced with smoke. Correct?

Comment: If you keyframe the material, and in the next frame keyframe it transparent, you won't see the object 'becoming invisible'. it will just disappear. Another way, is to animate image sets of the object as you want it to be. Then animate the smoke as you want it to be. (either as a duplicate object, or in a second file.) Then, create your final anim in the compositor, transitioning from solid to smoke however you like.